# Is there a way to get Server 2008 to *appear* as Vista for installers?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-server-2008, installation, compatibility

I have a tool that I want to install on my main development box (Windows Server 2008). The installer tells me that it requires Vista. Of course I'm not saying Server 2008 is Vista, but I figure something that installs on Vista should be able to install on Server 2008.

Is there some way (perhaps via a temporary registry change) to get a server 2008 system to appear as Vista for the purpose of installing software?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Win2008Workstation has an example guide](http://www.win2008workstation.com/wordpress/2008/03/29/installing-unreal-tournament-3/) of how to use Orca to patch an MSI file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the emulator for running the install, when right clicking and going in to the properties of the installer?

right click > properties > compatiblity > and change the compatibility mode to Windows XP or Windows Server 2003

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "tried the emulator for running the install". Right clicking on the installer and going into properties doesn't seem to show anything obvious.

Comment: Nick, there is no compatibilty tab for the MSI under server 2008. Good try though.

Comment: Weird, it shows up for everything else.  Oh well, I see that you found your solution.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

- If it's an MSI installer, [download orca](http://www.google.se/search?hl=sv&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=Dqq&q=orca+download+msi&btnG=S%C3%B6k&meta=) and delete the custom action that does the check
- Use a tool such as [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to watch what registry keys the installer reads and tweak them to match vista's.